# Podman can not kill containers: not running, but state improper

Tags: kill, container, podman

When I run `podman container kill -a`, I get

```
can only kill running containers. 11d887d57069b3ee630fd6f1b13d600485c34f5020ff09fec65f4e31dd7242a5 is in state configured: container state improper
can only kill running containers. 2132c0543eedbe3c4ee8680da508fea6251d38107d5e707f260eb5aa8549409d is in state configured: container state improper
can only kill running containers. 2db317cc73ec92e434fda88653f872e4c4cf07e9f32c0c29ecc5e69515beb96d is in state exited: container state improper
can only kill running containers. 465d133dec7a568bd8a6231036e1c489b6a6f88c65154629d75ce4161fb6e3c4 is in state exited: container state improper
```

Subsequent runs still show the containers. How can I get rid of them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that this is a bug because containers that are not running should not be targeted with `podman kill -a`

I was able to get rid of these containers by running

```
podman container rm -fa
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix by doing the following:

1. in the error message it will say ... is already in use by [long ID].  Copy that ID.
2. type podman restart [ID]
3. Type podman kill -a to kill all (this should now work), or use the command to kill a specific container.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen those issues only a few times. They are hard to get out of.

I found that the best was to try first

```
 $ podman container kill -fa
```

If that did not work, then use the really big hammer:

```
 $ podman system reset
 $ podman system reset     ; yes, twice.
 $ podman system renumber  ; gets rid of ...id already in use by...
```

I hope that helps! It saved me at a customer site!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).